# How to save instance of an activity using Jetpack library

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack

I need to store a large amount of data. Let’s say I need to store the list of users and their profile picture when the app going to rotate my app is crashed. Is there any trick how I can store the data?

Comment: What do you mean 'using jetpack'? If you use ViewModel, all your data should be stored there.

Comment: @ArtemBotnev i also have a alert dialogue when dialogue is open and activity rotate app is crash :(

Comment: Add a boolean value ( dialog is shown or not), you can also store data from dialog into ViewModel. In activity onDestroy() dismiss dialog. When check if dialog is shown in onStart() and show it again

Comment: See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/ and possibly https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-app-with-arch-components/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank's let me check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your data as a `file` or in Room and read if afterwards. ViewModel is not created to store huge sets of data.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: i think you are right because i have huge set of data . thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple data you can use onSaveInstanceState but since you have a large data, you can store your data using Room and integrate ViewModel class to handle configuration change. Can you post your code?
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: Technically ViewModel is just a cache across config change, image should be persisted to disk as a file.